# Semi-negative appearance on 2 linked Android tablet's icons/widgets, why?

Tags: screen, app-widgets, app-icons

1. Using 2 (LINKED) Android Tablets (1-older & 1-new).
2. Recently BOTH tablets have displayed

   - The screen photo in a semi-negative appearance (appx 1/2 colored) &
   - Widgets/icon buttons are nearly all black & white with a little touch of color in some. (Ex: Google Gmail button has a black circle, white center & semi-colored letter.)
3. Have turned Dark Mode OFF, checked Wallpapers & Contrasts but they appear ok. Rebooted too.

How do I change this back to normal or is it corrupted &/or non-repairable?

Comment: Sorry, but can you please explain what "Semi-Negative Appearance" means?

Comment: Could you mention the device model, Android version, and possibly the home screen app? For "*Widgets/icon buttons are nearly all black & white with a little touch of color in some*", this looks similar to "Themed icons". Otherwise, the "*semi-negative appearance*" might be caused by "Color correction" accessibility.